# transformar resultado em uma array so -function select php

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar uma function para fazer `select` na Base de Dados. Porém ele agora esta trazendo um array dentro do array. Como deixar em um array só.
Código que criei :

```
 <?php

include 'conect.php';
function select($con,$tabela,$colunas,$where=1){

    $sql ="SELECT $colunas FROM $tabela WHERE $where";
    $executar= mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
    $colunasdivididas = explode(",", $colunas);
    $numerodecolunas = count($colunasdivididas);
    $numrow= mysqli_num_rows($executar);
    $iii=1;
    $numero=['numeroderetorno'=>2];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($executar)){
        if($colunas!='*' AND $numerodecolunas>0 ){


                for($l=0;$l<$numerodecolunas;$l++){
                        $array[$colunasdivididas[$l].'-'.$iii] = $row[$colunasdivididas[$l]];

                }

        }elseif($colunas=='*'){

        }else{

                $array[$colunasdivididas[$l].'-'.$iii] = $row[$colunasdivididas[$l]];

        }
    $iii++;

    }
    $arraynumrow=['reposta'=>$numrow];
    $arrays=$arraynumrow+$array;

    return $arrays;
}
$ts=selectfuncionarios($link,'dono','id,login,senha');
    print_r($ts);
    ?>
```

resultado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quais parâmetros você tá passando pra sua função no momento do teste?

Comment: Teria como copiar todo o código do arquivo PHP ?

Comment: @RonaldoAmaral , esse seria todo o codigo pois e essa function que estou criando o resto seria so chamando ela tipo
´$chamar=selectfuncionarios('nometabela','nomecoluna','condiçaoseouver');´

Comment: @tropicoder12 esse parâmetros,  selectfuncionarios('dono','id,login,senha');

Comment: Não funciona se você simplesmente eliminar uma camada de array? Ex: $array[$colunasdivididas[$l].'-'.$iii] = $row[$colunasdivididas[$l]];

Comment: O seu código tem algumas lógicas bem complexas que não tenho certeza que sejam necessárias.

Comment: @ThiagoYou, basicamente  oq estou tentando fazer e uma function que retorne em array a resposta do select, e um modo para que possa usar o select so chamando a function e informando os dados

Comment: @ThiagoYou coloque sua resposta :"$array[$colunasdivididas[$l].'-'.$iii] = $row[$colunasdivididas[$l]];" no post pois deu certo obg

Comment: @CyberHacker Publiquei a resposta :)

Comment: Na verdade, esse código está uma bagunça. Acho que é uma boa ideia que as respostas refatorem e refaça-o, com uma nova ideia. Não faz sentido a função chamar `selectfuncionarios` e ainda ter que passar por parâmetro o nome da tabela. Sem contar a falta de indentação e um `for` dentro de um `while`. Se eu tiver tempo, posso ajudar a elaborar algo.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, igual eu falei sou novo no php, gostaria muito se vc tiver um tempo poder me ajudar a melhorar, o nomo que dei da function foi so para ficar obivio oq ela facia kkk

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, a minha ideia era evitar ter que repedir os parametro 'mysqli_fetch_array' e outros assim a pessoa seria capas de fazer o select no banco de dados apenas informando a tabela o nome das calunas e se a ou n uma condição assim em uma linha so ela ira fazer o select no banco e depois e so tratar ele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que está function um pouco mais simplificada deva funcionar. Apenas removi alguns elementos desnecessários e diminui uma camada de array que você estava inserindo:

**Array com uma camada a menos:**

```
$array[$colunasdivididas[$l].'-'.++$ii] = $row[$colunasdivididas[$l]];
```

**PHP Funtion Simplificada:**

```
function selectfuncionarios($tabela, $colunas = '*', $where = 1) {
    include 'conect.php';

    $sql = "SELECT $colunas FROM $tabela WHERE $where";
    $executar = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $colunasdivididas = explode(',', $colunas);

    $ii = 1;
    $numero = ['numeroderetorno' => 2];
    $array = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($executar)) {
        if ($colunas != '*' && count($colunasdivididas) > 0) {
            for ($l = 0; $l < count($colunasdivididas); $l++) {   
                $array[$colunasdivididas[$l].'-'.++$ii] = $row[$colunasdivididas[$l]];
            }            
        } elseif ($colunas=='*') {

        } else {
            $array[$colunas.'-'.++$ii] = $row[$colunas];
        }
    }

    return json_encode($array);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($executar)){
    if($colunas!='*' AND $numerodecolunas>0 ){


         for($l=0;$l<$numerodecolunas;$l++){
             $array[$ii] = array_push( $array , ($ii=>$row[$colunasdivididas[$l]]));

             $ii++;
         }

    }elseif($colunas=='*'){

    }else{
        $array = array_push( $array , ($colunasdivididas[$l]=>$row[$colunasdivididas[$l]])) );

    }


}
```

Comment: isso n interfere, eu coloque patrao ti vai ficar isso caso a pessoa n coloque uma condição
$sql ="SELECT $colunas FROM $tabela WHERE 1";

Comment: @CyberHacker Se queres juntar os arrays em um só porque não usas o array_merge()? https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp

Comment: Pensei nisso, porem a function select que estou fazendo e para ser usado em qualquer lugar, mesmo eu sabendo o tanto de colunas o usuario esta chamando e quantas vezes ela ira passar pelo wilhe usando o num_rows, n deu certo pois n aceito for($i=0:$i<$ii;$i++)$ts .= array_merge($array[i]);
ele ta arayarrayarray

Comment: @CyberHacker e se for assim? Editei a resposta para usar o metodo array_push, assim adiciona o elemento no fim do array em cada cyclo do for, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php?

Comment: estarei dando uma olhada obrigado

Answer (score -3):

Tente colocar o resultado em um while. ex:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {             
    $posts['post_id'] = $row['post_id'];
    $posts['post_title'] = $row['post_title'];
    $posts['type'] = $row['type'];
    $posts['author'] = $row['author'];  
}
```

Comment: e como iria fazer para trazer no return?